# Is it possible, in python, to update or initialize a dictionary key with a single command?

Tags: python, dictionary

For instance, say I want to build an histogram, I would go like that:

```
hist = {}
for entry in data:
    if entry["location"] in hist:
        hist[entry["location"]] += 1
    else:
        hist[entry["location"]] = 1
```

Is there a way to avoid the existence check and initialize or update the key depending on its existence?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

What you want here is a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
hist = defaultdict(int)
for entry in data:
    hist[entry["location"]] += 1
```

`defaultdict` default-constructs any entry that doesn't already exist in the dict, so for ints they start out at 0 and you just add one for every item.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can do:

```
hist[entry["location"]] = hist.get(entry["location"], 0) + 1
```

With reference types, you can often use `setdefault` for this purpose, but this isn't appropriate when the right hand side of your `dict` is just an integer.

```
Update( hist.setdefault( entry["location"], MakeNewEntry() ) )
```

Answer (score 8):

I know you've already accepted an answer but just so you know, since Python 2.7, there's also the `Counter` module, which is explicitly made for such situations.

```
from collections import Counter

hist = Counter()
for entry in data:
    hist[entry['location']] += 1
```

http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: I didn't even know that existed, but it's pretty much purpose-built for this (even more so than defaultdict(int), although the two seem pretty similar). Nice.

Comment: Yep, it's handy, though I've learned the hard way that the 2.7 version dependency limits its deployment in end-user applications for now.

Answer (score 1):

Is ternary operator one command?

```
hist[entry["location"]] = hist[entry["location"]]+1 if entry["location"] in hist else 1
```

(edited because I messed it up the first time)